# Data attributes inside a link_to helper method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I am having a hard time with the right syntax.
How can I use the link_to method in Rails to provide the same effect as:

```
<a data-photo-swipe-item="" data-size="1170x600" href="images/portfolio/portfolio-19-1170x600.jpg"><img width="570" height="420" src="images/portfolio/portfolio-19-570x420.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

**I want to add the "data-photo-swipe-item" and the "data-size" options inside this block:**

```
<%= link_to (image_path("portfolio-05-1170x600.jpg")) do %>
  <%= image_tag("portfolio-05-570x420.jpg", alt: "", :size => "570x420") %>
<% end %>
```

I have tried it multiple times. For Example:

```
<%= link_to (image_path("portfolio-05-1170x600.jpg"), "data-photo-swipe-item" => "", "data-size" => "1170x600") do %>
  <%= image_tag("portfolio-05-570x420.jpg", alt: "", :size => "570x420") %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to (image_path("portfolio-05-1170x600.jpg"), "data-photo-swipe-item" => "", "data-size" => "1170x600") do %>
  <%= image_tag("portfolio-05-570x420.jpg", alt: "", :size => "570x420") %>
<% end %>
```

But it still does not work!

**How can I accomplish this?**

If you need further information just let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
<%= link_to image_path("portfolio-05-1170x600.jpg"), data: { 'photo-swipe-item' => "", 'size' => '1170x600' } do %>
  <%= image_tag("portfolio-05-570x420.jpg", alt: "", :size => "570x420") %>
<% end %>
```